# Why Two row SQL Statement getting error in VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

When i write two row SQL query in VBA, i get an error. But when wrote one row query, it is running true. **Example**

```
Sub Run_Report()
Dim Server_Name As String

Server_Name = "SRV2"

Call Connect_To_SQLServer(Server_Name, "Kn_v3", "SELECT TOP (1000) *  FROM [d].[dbo].[AllBanks]")
End Sub


IT is running but below code is getting error;

Sub Run_Report()
Dim Server_Name As String

Server_Name = "SRRP2"

Call Connect_To_SQLServer(Server_Name, **"Kn_v3", "SELECT TOP (1000) *
FROM [ ].[dbo].[AllBanks]"**)
End Sub
```

---

Reason of this question, my query is bigger than one row. So i must use it on 2 row.

Comment: Use underscore "_" as line continuation. BTW there is no "real" need to have newline in an SQL query. You can write it all on one line as well, so having multiple lines is only about readability.

Comment: I couldn't find a duplicate with a usable answer so I wrote one myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the VBA syntax a newline is significant. Each statement is ended by a newline.
Therefore a statement such as

```
myString = "first line of the string
second line of the string"
```

Will return a syntax error because the first line contains a string definition that is missing the closing double quotes.

So you should make sure that you either put the complete statement on one line

```
myString = "first line of the string second line of the string"
```

Or you do it in two statements

```
myString = "first line of the string" 
myString = MyString & "second line of the string"
```

But now you are still missing your newline. You can add that into the mix like this

```
myString = "first line of the string" & vbNewLine &  "second line of the string"
```

Or in the multiple line variant

```
myString = "first line of the string" & vbNewLine
myString = MyString  & "second line of the string"
```

Now the first variant become hard to read if there are many line, and the second variant has each time has the part `myString = MyString  &` which is annoying.

You can avoid all that with the line continuation character `_` (underscore)

Then you end up with this way of defining multiple line strings in your code

```
myString = "first line of the string" & vbNewLine & _
           "second line of the string" & vbNewLine & _
           "third line of the string" & vbNewLine & _
           "fourth line of the string"
```

Which is my favorite variant